# Change one edge MST

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, minimum-spanning-tree

What is the best algorithm to find the MST in a new graph G'(E,V,w'), where we increase the weight of one edge in graph G (the edge can or can't be in the original MST).

I read that it is possible to do it in sqrt(E), but i didn't find the algorithm.

Thanks...

Comment: Try `cs.stackexchange.com` instead.

Comment: There is a simple case for this problem. If the edge is not in the original MST then it cannot be in the new MST as well.

Comment: If the edge is in the original MST, remove this edge from the MST should CUT the MST into two MST that connects the two partitions of V. Find the edge between these two partitions with the least cost should join them back as a new MST.